# FirebaseUI Recycler View for Chat 2 Different Holder Not Applied Correctly AFTER Scrolling

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm making a chat app. There are 2 views same viewholder.
The problem is, when I scroll to the top, the image, name not correctly inserted as suppose. 
I'm using Firebase Ui Recycler View for Realtime Database.

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AdminMessage, AdminChatViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdminChatViewHolder adminChatViewHolder, int i, @NonNull AdminMessage adminMessage) {

adminChatViewHolder.getTvMessage().setText(adminMessage.getMessage());



                //We retrieve the userUid to get real time name
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("admin").child(adminMessage.getSenderUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            Admin admin = dataSnapshot.getValue(Admin.class);
                            if (admin != null) {
                                final String nameAdmin = admin.getFullName();
                                final String profileUrl = admin.getProfileUrl();

                                //And then display
                                adminChatViewHolder.getTvName().setText(nameAdmin);

                                //Check for image if null or not (profileUrl)
                                if (profileUrl != null) {
                                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                            .load(profileUrl)
                                            .into(adminChatViewHolder.getImageView());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }


            @NonNull
            @Override
            public AdminChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view;
                if (viewType == VT_SENDER) {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_admin_message_sender, parent, false);
                } else {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_admin_message_receiver, parent, false);
                }
                return new AdminChatViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                if (getItem(position).getSenderUid().equals(userUid)) {
                    return VT_SENDER;
                }
                return VT_RECEIVER;
            }
        };
```

Comment: what you are trying to do in onBindViewHolder ?

Comment: @abdul using the userUid from onBindViewHolder and then get value from database

Comment: i think this is causing issue, as it is retrieving data from firebase at run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I remember I had the same issue before. I will try to remember all I can and update this answer.

Always empty the image view or hide it when there isn't an image or url fails:

```
if (profileUrl != null) {
   Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
        .load(profileUrl)
        .into(adminChatViewHolder.getImageView());
}
else
{
  //TODO: set an image place holder or hide adminChatViewHolder.getImageView()
}
```

I like to empty the imageView while waiting for the new one to load
and do the same for all views not just imageView (i.e. textview)
What if admin is null? what happens?

Don't forget to **call** `super.onDataChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

```
   @NonNull
        @Override
        public AdminChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view;
            if (viewType == VT_SENDER) {
             View   view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_admin_message_sender, parent, false);
               return new AdminChatViewHolder(view);
            } else {
              View  view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_admin_message_receiver, parent, false);
                 return new AdminChatViewHolder(view);
            }

        }
```

if you are query is right and your retrieving data is correct then you need to need new view every time ti display

Comment: still same. the data not put as correctly when scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be the async query from Firebase data. You put the update view logic in the `onDataChange`. However, if you scroll very fast to the top, the row is already recycled and reused. In this case, if the `onDataChange` triggered after the row is recycled, the content could set to the wrong target view.

What you can do is to move the data retrieval logic back to the `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` by setting a proper query to retrieve the `Admin` object or use the `AdminMessage` passed into the `onBindViewHolder` function.

You can refer to step 12 in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/android-grid/how-to-use-firebaserecycleradpater-with-latest-firebase-dependencies-in-android-aff7a33adb8b) to see what onBindViewHolder suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty straight forword, and I see you are trying to fetch some detail of the UID you provided. I did create a chat app available [here](https://github.com/azizur-rehman/SSTalk) and something similar in it. I encountered this issue. The issue is related to the `image caching` `Glide` uses. Make use of [Glide Cache](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#cache-configuration). Also, you should use [placeholder](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#cache-configuration) and [error](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html#error) while loading images.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your VH initially onbind and make sure you cancel requests with Glide :)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you attach firebase listener in the `onBindViewHolder` - when you scroll, new listener is attached every time the method is called, which may result into a corrupted data in items if you will scroll fast, because the old async result may come into a new listener. It is quite common lifecycle error and it appears within lists, recycler views and even fragments and activities directly if the async logic handling is flawed.
To fix this in you case, use a method that was specifically designed for such cases in the `RecyclerViewAdapter` - `onViewRecycled`

It should look like this.

Firstly you need to define listener along with a database reference as a separate global variables in the adapter or viewholder class like this

```
DatabaseRefference ref;

ValueEventListener listener;
```

then in the `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(...){
...
listener = = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            Admin admin = dataSnapshot.getValue(Admin.class);
                            if (admin != null) {
                                final String nameAdmin = admin.getFullName();
                                final String profileUrl = admin.getProfileUrl();

                                //And then display
                                adminChatViewHolder.getTvName().setText(nameAdmin);

                                //Check for image if null or not (profileUrl)
                                if (profileUrl != null) {
                                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                            .load(profileUrl)
                                            .into(adminChatViewHolder.getImageView());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("admin").child(adminMessage.getSenderUid());
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
...
}
```

and then detach listener on view recycled event

```
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: StopsViewHolder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
        if (ref != null && listener != null)
            ref.removeEventListener(listener)
}
```

It may require some additional work since I haven't tested it in the IDE. Hope it helps.